# Encryptor with substitution cipher

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to understand how best to approach this question, I'm new to Java:

> Write a java method which encrypts a message with a simple
> substitution cipher:
>
> encryption and decryption
>
> Input:
> payload = "Cat & 5 DogS"
> Alpha arg = 5
> Beta arg = 3
>
> Output:
> Payload enciphered = "nDU & 5 sVHp"
>
> Explanation:
>
> - "C" has a value 2,(2*5+3) %26 =13, 13 corresponds to 'n'. (lowercase since "C" is capitalized)
> - "a" has a value of 0,(0*5+3) %26 = 3, 3 corresponds to "D" (capitalized because "a" is lowercase)
> - "". "&", "", "5" and "" are unchanged.

Comment: Take a string input and two integer inputs. Loop through the string character by character and apply the transform as explained in the example and output the result character.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, edit the question and add the code there.

Answer (score 1):

@kiner_shah, you mean something like this:

```
public Substitute()
{
    key = new byte[256];
    
    for(int i = -128; i < 128; i++)
    {
        list.add((byte)i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    Byte[] tmp = new Byte[256];
    tmp = list.toArray(tmp);

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        key[i] = tmp[i];        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic approach to the problem. It's kind of lengthy but it works just fine.
In fact, the solution is actually in your explanation.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   
   String plainText = "Cat & 5 DogS";
   
   for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++){       
        shiftCharacter(plainText.charAt(i));
   }

  }

public static void shiftCharacter(char toShift){

    char [] alphaL = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' ', '&', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    char [] alphaC = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',' ', '&', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    char newChar;
    for (int i = 0; i < alphaL.length; i++){

            if (alphaL[i] == toShift && i < 26){
                int index = ((i * 5 + 3)) % 26;
                newChar = alphaC[index];
                System.out.print(newChar);
            }
            else if (alphaC[i] == toShift && i < 26 ){
                int index = ((i * 5 + 3 )) % 26 ;
                newChar = alphaL[index];
                System.out.print(newChar);
            }
    
            else if (alphaL[i]  == toShift && i >= 26){
            newChar = alphaL[i];
            System.out.print(newChar);
        }
    }
    
}
}
```